# Using failFast with closure map breaks "parallel" step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Not sure if it's my limited knowledge of Groovy or a quirk in Pipeline `parallel` step. I can't make it accept `failFast` if I use map instead of passing each closure individually:

```
def map = [:]
map['spam'] = {
    node {
        echo 'spam'
    }
}
map['eggs'] = {
    node {
        echo 'eggs'
    }
}
parallel map // Works.
parallel spam: map['spam'], eggs: map['eggs'], failFast: true // Works.
parallel map, failFast: true // Fails with exception.
```

The exception with `failFast` is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{failFast=true}, {spam=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@51a382ad, eggs=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@718cb50d}]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:111)
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of threads while doing a parallel run ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
map.failFast = true
parallel map
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps a little if you add the optional syntax in. The second option is passing a new `Map` while the third option is passing your original `Map` and an additional named parameter. Honestly I'm not sure what it thinks is going on.

```
parallel(map)
parallel([
    spam: map['spam'],
    eggs: map['eggs'],
    failFast: true
])
parallel map, failFast: true
```

In any case I think the simplest thing would be this:

```
def map = [
    spam: {
        node {
            echo 'spam'
        }
    },
    eggs: {
        node {
            echo 'eggs'
        }
    },
    failFast: true
]
parallel map
```

or...

```
parallel ([
    spam: {
        node {
            echo 'spam'
        }
    },
    eggs: {
        node {
            echo 'eggs'
        }
    },
    failFast: true
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jesse Glick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356318/4583071).

Even if you use a for loop to create a parallel stages you can use the same code -

```
map.failFast = true
parallel map
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are offering solutions, but none of them explain the reason you were getting an exception.

To understand this, it's beneficial to read about [Groovy's named parameters](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_named_parameters_2).

In Groovy, to create a function that can accept named parameters, you have to declare it as a function that accepts a single `Map` parameter. Example:

```
void copy(Map params) {
    println params.src
    println params.dest
}
// The next two lines are equivalent:
copy([ src: '/etc/config', dest: '/home/john' ])
copy src: '/etc/config', dest: '/home/john'
```

However, this is wrong:

```
final map = [ src: '/etc/config' ]
// The next two lines are equivalent, and will throw an exception:
copy(map, [ dest: '/home/john' ])
copy map, dest: '/home/john'
```

So you're trying to call a function which expects a single map, but you're passing it two maps.

To see for yourself, try executing this test Groovy code locally, no need for Jenkins

```
def printArgs(...args) {
    println args.length
    println args.collect{ it.toString() }.join(', ')
}
            
def map = [ spam: 10, eggs: 20 ]
printArgs map // Single map
printArgs spam: map['spam'], eggs: map['eggs'], failFast: true // Single map
printArgs map, failFast: true // Two maps
```

Finally, a couple of alternative solutions that work without modifying the original `map`:

```
// The next two lines are equivalent:
parallel map + [ failFast: true ]
parallel map.plus(failFast: true)
```